# canvas with IEF, "static" variable and event

Tags: javascript

I wrote a program in JavaScript that displays 5 rectangles, one after each other with a ~1s delay.
As there is no static variable in Javascript as in C or other languages, I used an IIEF that returns a function in a variable `draw` to have an internal counter that is visible only in the function. 
This code works perfectly.

```
let myCanvas=document.getElementById("my-canvas");

let draw=(function() {
    let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    let counter=0;
    return function() {
        if (counter<5) {
            ctx.fillRect(25+counter*20, 25, 10, 100);
            counter++;
            setTimeout(() => {window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)},1000);
        }
    }
})();

draw();
```

But now, I would like to fill the rectangle with a texture instead of the black color. Something like that :

```
let myPatternImg=new Image();
myPatternImg.onload = function() {
    let myPattern=ctx.createPattern(myPatternImg,'repeat');
    context.fillStyle=pattern;
        ... // code to draw rectangle
}
myPatternImg.src='pattern-file.png';
```

I do not how to do because when I initialize `draw` a function is returned directly. And this does not work with an onload event. I do not want a global variable for the counter. That is why I use an IIEF that returns a function to init the variable `draw`.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use promises, to hide pattern creation:

```
function makePattern(ctx, src) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
     let myPatternImg = new Image();
     myPatternImg.onload = function() {
        let myPattern = ctx.createPattern(myPatternImg, 'repeat');
        resolve(myPattern);
     };
     myPatternImg.src = src;
   });
}

let myCanvas=document.getElementById("my-canvas");

let draw = (function() {
    let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    let counter = 0;
    return function() {
        makePattern(ctx, 'pattern-file.png').then(function(pattern) {
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
            if (counter < 5) {
               ctx.fillRect(25+counter*20, 25, 10, 100);
               counter++;
               setTimeout(() => {window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)},1000);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

it's always good idea the separate your code into functions that do one thing.

But this code make little of sens, you are executing in a loop draw and each will draw 5 rectangles, I think that what you really want is something like this:

```
let draw = (function() {
    let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    let counter = 0;
    return function() {
        makePattern(ctx, 'pattern-file.png').then(function(pattern) {
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
            (function loop() {
               if (counter < 5) {
                  ctx.fillRect(25+counter*20, 25, 10, 100);
                  counter++;
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                  }, 1000);
                }
            })();
        });
    }
})();
```

also this will fire each rectangle after 1000 seconds, if you want delay between each rectangle to be 1 second then use this:

```
let draw = (function() {
    let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    let counter = 0;
    return function() {
        makePattern(ctx, 'pattern-file.png').then(function(pattern) {
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
            (function loop() {
               if (counter < 5) {
                  ctx.fillRect(25+counter*20, 25, 10, 100);
                  counter++;
                  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
                }
            })();
        });
    }
})();
```

if you call draw multiple times it will create pattern each time, you can make it request only once if you use this code:

```
let draw = (function() {
    let ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    let counter = 0;
    return function(pattern) {
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        (function loop() {
           if (counter < 5) {
              ctx.fillRect(25+counter*20, 25, 10, 100);
              counter++;
              setTimeout(loop, 1000);
            }
        })();
    }
})();

makePattern(ctx, 'pattern-file.png').then(draw);
```

Comment: My code draws only 5 rectangles one after each other because of the "static" counter variable.

Comment: Why not just create a single pattern (from that single file) only, and store it in the scope with the other contextual variables?

Comment: @jcubic. With promise, how can I be sure that draw is initialized when I call it ? The .then is done only when the promise has been resolved (i.e. after the onload has been executed).

Comment: @Bergi. But, when I call draw, I will not sure that the pattern will be initialized. It depends when the onload event has been raised.

Comment: @Stef1611 I meant using the `makePattern(…)` function from this answer, and storing the promise for the pattern. Yes, you will always need to wait for the promise, but you'll always get the same value and in the latter runs you get it almost immediately.

Comment: @Bergi. If I understand (I began to learn JS a few week ago), I must call draw() with a promise. Something like that promise.then(draw). Right ?

Comment: @Stef1611 if you call `promise.then(draw)`,  then you don't need promise inside draw, but `return function(pattern) {
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;` but there if you call draw in `setTimeout` you need call `draw(pattern)`

Comment: @Bergi. I ran the code in the answer. It works but the image file is loaded five times because the promise is in the returned function. How is it possible to do only one load ? I tried different things but it does not work.

Comment: @Stef1611 `let patternPromise = makePattern(…); return function() { patternPromise.then(pattern => { …`

Comment: @Bergi. Thanks a lot it works. To be sure I understand : the first time, patternPromise object is created and its state is _pending_ and `.then(function..)` is executed when the promise has been resolved. Now, the promise state is _fulfilled_. For the following `draw` calls (in `requestanimationframe`), a promise object is not created (because it is a "static" variable like counter) and the promise is still in state _fulfilled_, so `.then(function..)`is directly executed. Right ?

Comment: @Stef1611 The `patternPromise` (and the `ctx` and the `counter`) are created when `draw` is initialised/created, not when it is called for the first time. (And that means the image is always loaded, even when `draw()` is never called). Apart from that, you're right.

Comment: @Bergi. Thanks a lot for your help. Don't you think the answer could edited with your very constructive comments.

Comment: @jcubic. Thanks a lot for your help. Don't you think the answer could edited with your very constructive comments.

Comment: @Stef1611 I've added one more snippet of code, if you think that it would benefit of having comments in the answer, you can add it yourself if you want.